# Access Controls from UserControls in ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Access Controls from UserControls in ASPX page?
For example:
I want to access gridview which is in usercontrol on ASPX page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to provide properties in your `UserControl` that you can access.

For example:

```
public GridView UserGrid
{
     get
     {
         return GridView1;
     }
}
```

But the question is why you need this.

**Rule of thumb**: Only expose as few as possible. On that way your code will be most robust and readable. So it would e.g. better to expose it's `DataSource` rather than the complete `GridView`.

On the other hand, if you want your page to react on events in your UserControl, it should provide custom events(e.g. *UserDeleted*) that your page then can handle.

[Page-UserControl-Commmunication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3)

Answer (score 0):

Because the controls now nothing about eachother at the same level, you have to use the parent page to get it. Try this logic:

1. Create a property referring to your parent page (the page your control usually is in (might be different because of layering of controls)
2. Create a property on your page referring to the usercontrol the grid is in, or link to that grid directly.

page.aspx

```
public UserControl UserGridControl
{
     get;
     set;
}
```

userControl.ascx

```
public Page ParentPage
{
     get;
     set;
}
```

Example call:

Instantiate the properties first. After that, use the following statement to access anything from that control (as an example I used Foo() here, to use as a dummy method, but it seems it was unclear to someone):

otherControl.ascx:

```
this.ParentPage.UserGridControl.Foo();
```

EDIT: Want to have a direct code example to be able do it from the **page** only? See Tim Schmelters answer. If you need a way to call the grid from another user control as well. Use mine.

Comment: What is `Foo`? It's nowhere declared. I also don't see the purpose of your `ParentPage` property. The OP has asked how to access the UserControl's GridView which is in an ASPX-Page from within this page. So it's redundant.

Comment: Are you really criticising a more broad answer? I've only given the OP an extra way to load it from another user control as well... Is that so bad?

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer(although parts seem to be copied from mine), so your answer is not _bad_, but it adds nothing and doesn't reference the OP's requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry for copying your property definition (after I had written the text version of the solution first). I've could've written it myself, but if we would write every piece of code ourselves from scratch, we would be out of jobs. I've never said your answer was wrong. I'm just providing a way to do it from another user control as well. Given the fact that the OP only provided a really short question, our solutions both could be correct. I've had this (related) problem before and in the end, StackOverflow is a source of knowledge. This solution can be adapted to be used from a page as well.

Comment: I've edited the post to refer to yours if it's only needed from the page level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
GridView GridView1 = (GridView)WebUserControl1.FindControl("GridView1");
```

Where WebUserControl1 is ID of use control on .aspx page.

Hope this helps..